# Does $f(\mathbb{Q}^n) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ hold only for rational functions?

Tags: rational-numbers, rational-functions

Let $f$ be a $C^{\infty}$-function from an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
If $f(\mathbb{Q}^n\cap U) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ can we conclude that $f$ is a rational function?

Comment: You wrote that the domain of $f$ is an open subset. If the domain is not $\Bbb R^n$, then the expression $f(\Bbb Q^n)$ does not make sense. I have edited the question to avoid this problem.

Comment: I'd say at first glance that the answer is "no", but finding a counterexample seems hard...